# Remote activation/deactivation and protecting against out of business

Tags: activation

I'm in charge of an app that uses the internet to transfer data between sites, and some customers are being awkward about paying, so we need a mechanism that will allow us to cut off the service of non-payers. I'd like to protect against the admin people using firewalls to block off our checks, but conversely I'd like to give some allowance for our company web site disappearing for some reason and not being accessible.

The scheme I'm imagining is:

```
server makes twice daily check to web page using a URL like:
http://www.ourcompany.com/check.php?myID=GUID&Code=MyCode
```

This then returns a response that contains either nothing of interest, or the GUID and a value.

```
GUID=0
```

That zero indicates that the server should stop operation. To make it work again, the server will check every 5 mins for the same info, until the value matches what it thinks the code that it passed in should be transformed to.

This scheme makes sense to me, but the question really is how to protect against blocking. Given we know we must have internet access, how long should we continue to operate without being able to get the response from our web server? Is something like 14 days and then we just shut it off anyway the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used in the end was pretty much as I suggested. Yes, it is defeatable using tools outlined here, but it is better than nothing.

The app checks daily to access a web site that contains a control file encrypted using public key encryption. It decrypts in memory, and if it finds its GUID, then it must match a code. To disable the operation, the code is set to 0 (zero) which will always fail. When disabled, it checks every two minutes to allow rapid restoration. There is also a manual mechanism to generate a code that will work for a week in case of server trouble.

The code will allow up to 14 days without connecting to the server before it takes this as a deliberate attempt to block it. After 10 days, it shows an error message which asks them to contact support.

Answer (score 0):

This method is really easy to circumvent: just use a local dns server to point www.ourcompany.com to the local machine, or use a http proxy. Then the user can return whatever response they want to the program.

Assuming the user hasn't circumvented the check, how long you are to continue to operate without confirmation is a business decision and not a programming decision.

Comment: Hmm, yes. Okay, we'll go with a public key encrypted file so that we must have a good download and decode or it "fails". Business or programming decision? Perhaps, but it is for me, the programmer, to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

A user can use a tool such as OWASP WebScarab to change values on the fly to subvert your security model. You need to include something more difficult such as requiring a secure channel, comparing public key and so on.